# How can I restore a 10.91G table in Oracle Express?

Tags: oracle, restore

I've received a `.dmp` file of an enterprise database, but currently only have access to a free version of Oracle. I would ultimately like to import the data to PostgreSQL. But currently am wondering if there's a way to restore the largest table (10.91G) in chunks if need be, so I can export its contents to csvs to import into PostgreSQL. Currently if I try to selectively restore the 10.91GB table with

```
impdp system/pw tables=TEST.BIG_TABLE directory=test_data dumpfile=test_data.dmp log=log.log;
```

I get

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-31694: master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_TABLE_01" failed to load/unload
ORA-02354: error in exporting/importing data
ORA-39776: fatal Direct Path API error loading table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_TABLE_
01"
ORA-12953: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 11 GB
```

The largest Tablespace I've been able to create so far was of `SIZE 10500M`, the command:
`CREATE TABLESPACE test DATAFILE 'test.dbf' SIZE 10600M ONLINE;` produced error `ORA-12953: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 11 GB`

The results of `select tablespace_name, sum(bytes) from dba_data_files group by tablespace_name` are:

```
tablespace | sum(bytes)/1000000
-----------+-------------------
SYSAUX     | 692.06016
UNDOTBS1   | 398.45888
USERS      | 104.8576
SYSTEM     | 524.288
TEST       | 11010.048
```

Comment: I think the 11GB limit includes the preinstalled system data. Oracle XE will never allow you to import this much data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space a table takes up and the space it needs can differ.

I'd recommend using impdp with the sqlfile option to put the create table script into a file. Edit that to try to maximise the use of space (set pctfree to 0). Remove any primary key or unique constraint, as any index will eat into your available storage.

The INITIAL will be the amount of space initially allocated. Start with whatever is in the sqlfile output and nudge the value down until the create statement succeeds. Then use impdp with TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=TRUNCATE so it will insert the data into the already created table.

Cross your fingers that there's enough room. If not, you can look at applying a WHERE clause as part of the impdp and split the data into two.

Comment: Clarifying question: What do I do with the `sqlfile.sql`? After your suggested modifications do I run that as a query in SQL Developer? (I think yes, just wanted it noted for anyone else coming along)

Comment: Finally got it in, had to also include a `WHERE` clause to split the data in half.

Answer (score 1):

This is important

> ORA-12953: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 11 GB

Maybe if you try to use "query" in impdp you can import less data...

example:

```
impdp bert/bert directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=all_of_movies.dmp schemas=movies query=\"where last_mod_date is not null and last_mod_date > SYSDATE-90\"
```

Comment: I've updated the error message I got, but this is a good point about how to chunk the import. First to figure out the extents of a particular column I could filter on...